# How to target children of all descendants but the first

Tags: jquery

I want to target child `<ul>` of parent `<li>` of all `lis` but the first children of the main ul but I cannot get it to work.

```
<ul class="some_ul">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drop 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.some_ul > li').addClass('first_li');

$('.some_ul li:not(.first_li)').children('ul').css({
    'position': 'relative',
    'left': 200
});
```

So basically I am trying to target the second ul, and any ul that comes after it.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BWkA9/)

Comment: Sorry, but this is very unclear. Are you just looking for `li ul`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector. Like this:

```
$('.some_ul li:not(:first)').children('ul').css({ //...
```

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/6yBef/

Answer (score 1):

`$('.some_ul > li').addClass('first_li');` isn't doing what you want. `>` selects all direct descendants, so your example is adding the class `first_li` to all `li`s directly under it.

I think you want something like this instead:

```
$('.some_ul > li').not(":first").children('ul').css({
    'position': 'relative',
    'left': 200
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92Dsq/

Answer (score 1):

> So basically I am trying to target the second ul, and any ul that
>   comes after it.

To be overly specific :

```
$('ul.some_ul > li > ul').children('ul').addBack();
```